# Looping through rows/columns of each *page* in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to do a standard loop for each Page in my worksheet. The outer loop is rows, the inner loop is columns. In case the page layout changes, I want the loop to automatically adjust to the new boundaries.

Is there anyway to find the beginning and end rows and columns for each Page?

I have already tried using the VPageBreaks and HPageBreaks objects from the Worksheet object, but this doesn't work if there aren't actual page breaks in the Worksheet.

Comment: Try the using `Worksheet.UsedRange`

Comment: @netspear777 Welcome to stackoverflow! If you show the code what you've tried, you can surely find help here

Comment: `Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` and `Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlLeft).Column` Easy Google.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ws.UsedRange` property to get the last row and column. If you are trying to loop through different **worksheets**, then the code below should work.

```
Sub loop_through_all()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Integer, c As Integer

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

        For r = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            For c = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count

                ' Your code goes here

            Next
        Next

    Next

End Sub
```

If you are trying to loop through **pages** as you would see them on a worksheet, then realize it's all one giant sheet. If you have data shown in "tables" throughout your sheet and you want to parse them individually, then it will take a bit more work and you should use the `.End()` method.

```
Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Comment: `UsedRange` is a lot more dangerous than the `End()` method.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the `.End()` method requires you to specify a row/column that should define the extents of your data. If it's not guaranteed from sheet to sheet to have the same row, it might not be as effective. Aside from the fact that `UsedRange` can pick up a stray cell way out of the range you're expecting (and thus take a bit longer to process) is there any other harm?

Comment: You are correct you need to know the largest column and row, but if you are designing your sheets correctly, you should know this to be the first column and the first row as they should be the headers for that particular row and column.